# Can't get Angular4 to work with lazy loading and animation (using BrowserAnimationsModule)

Tags: angular

Can't get Angular4 to work with lazy loading and animation.
So I loaded `BrowserAnimationsModule` in my app-modules.ts and animation works fine in main module, but not in lazy loaded modules, so I tried to load
`BrowserAnimationsModule`in my shared module as I get an error of :
`Unhandled Promise rejection: BrowserModule has already been loaded.
 If you need access to common directives`

This is my shared module:

```
var sharedComponents = [Tabs, Tab, Infobox, Sliderpanel, Slideritem, SlideritemContent, PanelSplitMain, PanelSplitSide, PanelSplitContainer, ListToArrayPipe, FormatSecondsPipe, MatchBodyHeight, ScreenTemplate, BlurForwarder, DraggableList, AddContent, Loading,
    FontSelector, BlockPropContainer, BlockPropCommon, BlockPropHtml, BlockPropClock, BlockPropWeather, BlockPropInstagram, BlockPropJsonPlayer, BlockPropJsonItem, LivePreview, LocationMap, MediaPlayer, FilterModelPipe, SvgIcon,
    BlockPropScene, BlockPropCalendar, BlockPropSheets, BlockPropTwitter, BlockPropVideo, BlockPropImage, BlockPropLabel, BlockPropMrss, BlockPropLocation, BlockPropRss, BlockPropDigg, BlockPropFasterQ, BlockPropCollection, BlockPropQR, BlockPropYouTube, JsonEventGrid];

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, JsonpModule, ReactiveFormsModule, ContextMenuModule, ChartModule, ReactiveFormsModule, ColorPickerModule, DropdownModule, RadioButtonModule, SimpleGridModule, Ng2Bs3ModalModule, AgmCoreModule, VgCoreModule, VgControlsModule, VgOverlayPlayModule, VgBufferingModule],
    exports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, JsonpModule, ReactiveFormsModule, ContextMenuModule, ChartModule, ColorPickerModule, DropdownModule, RadioButtonModule, SimpleGridModule, Ng2Bs3ModalModule, AgmCoreModule, VgCoreModule, VgControlsModule, VgOverlayPlayModule, VgBufferingModule, ...sharedComponents],
    entryComponents: [ScreenTemplate],
    declarations: [...sharedComponents]
})

export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: []
        };
    }
}
```

and as soon as I add to it the `BrowserAnimationsModule` it will error out,

ideas?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: So are you saying it is in the shared module and the main app.module?

Comment: I don't really mind setting it up any way, as long as it works, tried all diff combinations and no go :/ ... both just in main as well as in main + lazy load module..

Comment: @born2net did you ever solve this?

Comment: @born2net did you?

Comment: try adding the import of BrowserAnimationsModule to app.module

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can only import BrowserModule or BrowserAnimationsModule and it has to be in the root app module as explained in this github issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15579

The solution is to import BrowserAnimationsModule only on app.module

Just posting here if anyone stumbles across the same issue

Comment: But how do you get animation capabilities in a lazy loaded child module in that case? It doesn't seem to work for me :/